# Travelling to the USA, but want to stay longer than 3 months? is this possible? UK citizen

Tags: visas, usa, us-visa-waiver-program, uk-citizens

I want to travel to the USA (I am UK Citizen) and I am only allowed 90 days.

Is it possible for me to stay longer - say 6 months to a year, and how?

Comment: Of course.  Obtain a B1/B2 visa and usually that allows a 6 months stay.

Comment: Thanks, but i cant find anywhere online thats says this is possible? is it possible to be denied a B1/B2?

Comment: It's possible to be denied just as it is possible to be denied an ESTA.  All you need to do is apply at the US Embassy or Consulate.

Comment: @Jlc the word *live* will get your visa request denied. You can visit for tourist purposes but if you show up at the border with a return ticket six months in the future prepare for some hard questions about how do you plan to afford your visit since you are not allowed to work.

Comment: @chx how difficult is it to get a working visa?

Comment: To the USA? On scale of 1-10 what about 9 or so?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61825/is-it-a-good-idea-to-mention-to-the-usa-immigration-officer-that-im-visiting-my.  It looks from that like US visa/immigration law is not particularly sympathetic to unmarried couples wanting to spend a lot of time together.

Comment: @Karlson That's a good answer to the question.

Answer (score 12):

The only way to stay in the US for more than 90 days is to obtain a B1/B2 visa, which will allow you to stay up to 6 months.

However in general the US is relatively strict regarding granting B1/B2 visas to people who are otherwise eligible to use the Visa Waiver Program (which allows for stays up to 90 days).  Generally they will be looking for a very good reason that you intend to stay for more than 90 days, and some level of guarantee that you will leave at the end of your stay.

Unfortunately visiting a girlfriend generally doesn't tick these boxes.  A 6 month stay also means that it's likely that you don't have a job to return to in the UK, and probably don't have a permanent UK residence to return to - if these are both true then your odds of having a visa approved are reduced even further.

The problem then becomes that if you do apply for a visa and it is rejected, you are no longer able to enter the US using the Visa Waiver Program - which means that you can't visit your girlfriend at all.

Nobody here can give you a definitive answer as nobody knows your exact situation or how the consulate staff will interpret that situation - but if it were me I would NOT be risking applying for a visa.

Comment: yeah this is what i thought. Thanks @Doc- Have i got any options?

Comment: What if i got a internship over there to do with my career?

Comment: An internship would require at least a J1 visa, and whilst that may be possible it's a lot of effort to obtain both the internship and the visa.

Comment: and if the j1 visa was denied- would the same apply as regards to the ESTA?

Comment: Yes.  Any visa denial means no VWP

Comment: @Jlc another option is a full-time course of study. I know someone who used that route to move in with her then-boyfriend, who was in the US for many years on a work visa.  Now they are married and are US citizens.

Comment: @phoog - if i did that is there  still a chance a visa in would be denied? which leaves me in the same situation?

Comment: @Jlc (delayed reply because I was on vacation): There's always a chance that any visa application will be denied.  I don't know what the denial rates are for people in full-time courses of study, but I would guess that they are low.  If you are looking for a guaranteed way to live in the United States (with a partner or otherwise), you will not find it.  What's more, if you are looking for a guaranteed way to enter the United States for *any length of time,* you won't find that, either.

Answer (score 8):

**Yes**

You will need to obtain a B1/B2 visa (not an ESTA with the Visa Waiver Program) at the nearest US embassy or consulate.

That allows up to 6 months stay upon entry.