# Too much time in the US? (using VWP)

Tags: esta, us-visa-waiver-program

Just looking for some opinions here before I begin planning my next US trip.

A little background first;

- I'm a UK citizen with a clean immigration history.
- I've made 4 short/medium length visits to the US in during 2011-2012
  (on the VWP)
- Visited friends in California from 18th June - 12th August 2015.
- Visited same friends again from 1st November '15 - 26th January '16.

So as you can see, I spent quite a bit of time in the States last year. I should note that I received no hassle at all after visiting again in November. If anything, it was the most friendly border crossing yet!

I'm about to go through some fun stressful times with moving to a new home. After settling down in my new home for a month or so, I'm considering another vacation in the US to meet with the same friends to unwind and enjoy the California summer for around 3-4 weeks.

I was already feeling nervous about considering a trip in mid-June, considering I will have only been back in the UK for a total of 5 months before flying back out again.  However after stupidly reading a couple of online articles from people who have received hassle from CBP over too many frequent visits, I'm now even more anxious.

So here's my question to you guys. Given my recent travel history, what is your opinion about me possibly travelling again in mid-June?  I would be travelling for a much shorter duration this time, most likely just for 3-4 weeks. Obviously I realise no one can give me a 100% answer since it'll be up to the CBP officer I meet on the day, but I'm still curious to know what you guys think.  Do you think it's too soon? Or am I stressing myself out unnecessarily?

Another point to add is that on both previous visits, I ended up extending my stay by 2-3 weeks more than originally planned. (The last trip extension was due to having a heavy cold, and wanting to fight it off before flying)  Even though both trips were still within the 90 day limit, will the fact I have a history of extending my flights be an issue? (I should note that I'm not intending to do it this time)

I should note that I would be able to bring documentation in regards to my new lease to show ties to the UK, along with evidence of plenty of funds to support my trip, and a return ticket of course.  I should also note that this is the only US trip I am planning for this year.

Thanks in advance for any opinions you guys may have for me!

Comment: You're worrying too much. Just pop over, swipe your passport in the kiosk and go right on to your holiday.

Comment: Much to our shock in http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61825/is-it-a-good-idea-to-mention-to-the-usa-immigration-officer-that-im-visiting-my someone presented a letter from CBP which says they are using the "if you spent X days in the US you need to be out X days" rule. If you were to go right now there might be problems but even as early as next week likely won't. June? Go for it.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance.  I've been under a little stress recently (namely related to my upcoming move, heh), so I think that's caused me to worry more than usual.  I think that vacation will do me the world of good, hah!

Thanks again!

Comment: I'd say your nervousness can work against you. It's possible that you'll get questions, but that doesn't mean you'll be sent back. Just try to stay calm and have a logical and coherent explanation for your travels. The more you can show ties to the UK (your lease, property, job, family, etc...), the stronger your position will be.

Comment: @chx: That's not actually what the depicted letter says. It says that if you spend 90 days you should be out 91 days before reentering -- but generalizing that from 90 to X and X (or X+1) is entirely in the eye of the beholder.