# Traveling from NZ to USA, how much money do I need for CBP to let me in?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, money, proof-of-funds, new-zealand-citizens

I'm traveling from New Zealand to North Carolina to stay with my partner for a number of weeks. My ESTA has been approved. While I'm staying with him, he will be covering my daily costs and necessities, meaning the only money I will spend will be on random things I see in stores. I will only have about 300NZD in my account when I arrive.

Is this enough to have CBP turn me away?

Comment: Why the Texas tag?

Comment: I arrive in Dallas

Comment: I want to say you're unlikely to have trouble. My mother in law who is supported in part by my wife and her sister has not been asked about her finances when visiting us (both her children live in the US). But she wasn't visiting her partner, so that could get you a different level of scrutiny. Also she doesn't speak much English. And you might just get an officer who woke up on the wrong side of the bed. Your partner might want to be ready to demonstrate his ability to support you during your trip, just in case. (A comment instead of a proper answer because I'm not totally confident in it.)

Comment: I'll have all his contact info so if they aren't satisfied with me as I am, will they contact him to confirm it before they take an action?

Comment: They ought to, but you can never be too sure. You will be traveling on a NZ passport?

Comment: I will be, yes.

Comment: CBP will likely not call your partner, as they are simply a voice on the phone, not proof, and you are solely responsible for proving that you are eligible to stay.  That said, as long as you are nicely dressed, not looking like a destitute backpacker, chances are the question won't come up unless your 'number of weeks' equal several months.

Comment: Are you married to your partner, or just in a relationship?  Do you have a credit card?

Comment: Americans tend not to carry much cash, at least, those of us who lived through the crime waves of the 1970s-80s. I echo @Doc, do you have a valid credit card you can say you will use?

Answer (score 5):

Upon entering the US **you will have to prove that you have sufficient funds to sustain yourself for the entire duration of stay in the US**. Much to our disappointment, the CBD does not specify how much is "enough funds". There is no fixed amount per day. Indeed, such an amount depends on spending habits, accomodation costs, transportation costs, shopping frenzies, etc. To give you an idea, saying that you'll be staying for a month at a 5* Hilton with 300NZD is likely to raise a few eyebrows.

In addition, you mention that your partner will be hosting you, and funding you, throughout your stay. You should carry a written confirmation of this to be shown to the CBP officer. [As the CBP puts it](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/796/%7E/foreign-visitor-having-to-carry-a-certain-amount-of-money-to-enter-the-u.s.):

> ### Does a foreign visitor have to carry a certain amount of money to enter the U.S.?
>
> **Yes.**  Travelers visiting the U.S. from a foreign country must be able to prove to a CBP Officer that they have sufficient funds (i.e. credit cards, cash, travelers checks, money orders etc.) to cover their travel, lodging, entertainment, meals, etc. in order to be admitted into the U.S.
>
> CBP Officers are aware that there may be circumstances in which a traveler may have limited funds. In those cases they will determine the admissibility of the traveler based on the information provided to support the reason the traveler has insufficient funds.
>
> If you have invited someone to visit you with the understanding that you will be hosting them at your house and providing meals, etc., it is advised that you confirm your invitation in writing so that they have something to show the CBP Officer. The letter should include your full name and address. This will not guarantee their admission into the U.S., but it will help the CBP Officer fully assess their situation.

You are also likely to face extra questioning since you plan on staying for a longish period to stay with your partner. This scenario is often a prequel to overstaying and illegal immigration. You should obviously not lie to the CBP officer. Be honest about your purpose of travel and make sure you have a convincing story about your intentions to leave the US. Showing strong ties to your home country - a job, education career, etc. - usually helps with this. We have a similar question of TSE with tips on the topic: [Is it a good idea to mention to the USA immigration officer that I'm visiting my girlfriend?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61825/is-it-a-good-idea-to-mention-to-the-usa-immigration-officer-that-im-visiting-my)