# ESTA return, does the “clock” reset when travelling across Panama - Cuba?

Tags: visas, usa, air-travel, international-travel, esta

I'm currently staying in the US under the ESTA, but later on I'll travel to Panama, then to Cuba, and from there through Mexico back to Miami, where I'm catching a flight back to London. The thing is, my ESTA 90 days period will end during my visit in Cuba, but as far as I know, visiting Panama should be reseting the 90 days “clock”. My question is, is the ESTA trip period going to be reseted despite of coming back to US through Mexico which doesn't apply for the 90days count reset? Will I have to proove that I've visted Panama as well?

Thank for any advices and sorry for the long post!

Comment: There is no such thing as "resetting 90 days clock". The clock is paused, not resetted.

Comment: @Neusser that is incorrect.  The clock is never paused.  The 90 days of the VWP are not like the 90 days of the Schengen area.

Comment: Also relevant: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79056/will-traveling-to-cuba-reset-my-esta?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Since you're reentering after the expiration of your 90-day period, the officer will have to admit you for a new period if you are in fact granted admission.  Therefore, you should not need to show that you've been outside North America.

There is some ambiguity in the application of the "contiguous territory" rule, however, so it may nonetheless be helpful to be able to show that you've been to Panama.