Just come back from US on a 90day ESTA, when can I return?
I came to Orlando Florida on the 1st of May for 3 weeks on an ESTA. I left on the 21st of May for work back in my home country, England.
I returned on 29th May and left 31st July. My girlfriend lives there she is a single mother of 7 children and I came over to help move house and help with children while she works.
I want to know when could I come back as I don't want go against laws and want to do everything right without being rejected at the border. My ESTA is valid until April 2026 and it says there is no limits to returning along as I don't over stay the 90 days but wanted to double check so I don't run into any problems when returning.

See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/190543/esta-renewal-advice

The rule of thumb (referenced in the earlier question cited by Midavalo) is that one should spend out of the US the same or more time as one spends in the US, to avoid being seen as one who is "living in the US" using repeated visitor entries. A fuller explanation of how ESTA time-keeping works can be found in this question.

Even if you do follow the law, be careful.  If you tell the border agent you are helping out your girlfriend with her seven children, they might (understandably) suspect immigration intent and deny you from entering the country.  The legal way to stay longer might be to get married or find another way to get residency (work visa).

help move house and help with children while she works both of them may be interpreted as work. It doesn't matter if you receive nothing back (probably lodging is considered something back in such case).
